# HTML5 Validation Error in Dreamweaver

Tags: html, css, image

This is a school project that I am working on, but there is something wrong with the Validation. I have images in the list, and I think that might be the problem. What should I do so that it validates correctly?

Here is a link to the live page.

http://noah-stahl.binhoster.com/bwm150/assignment_4/tech_history.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the only valid child of a `<ul>` element is a `<li>` element. Put the images inside the `<li>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

I would put them in div class to be a little more structure but that's just a personal preference.